# How to reduce image size in python turtle graphix

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I loaded an image on my turtle screen and I tiried to reduce it's size using tkinter but the zoom function does not accept decimals meaning it can't reduce sizeso I will like to know if there is any way to do it. Here's what I did

```
from turtle import Shape, Screen, Turtle
from tkinter import PhotoImage


wn = Screen()
wn.setup(width = 700, height = 1500)
wn.bgcolor('white')
pic = PhotoImage(file = "2.gif").zoom(1.1, 1.1)
wn.addshape('pic', Shape("image", pic))

tr = Turtle("pic")
while True:
    wn.update()
```

Comment: There is also a `.subsample()` method that does the opposite of `.zoom()` - but it's limited to integer scale factors, too.  You can combine them - `.zoom(11).subsample(10)` would be roughly equivalent to your attempt to scale by 1.1 - but you're probably not going to like the quality of the results.  The solution is to use an additional image-processing module such as Pillow.

Comment: You can use `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` to work with images. `Image` can load and modify image - resize, convert colors, add text, crop, etc. - and `ImageTk` can create `PhotoImage` for `tkinter` - it is often used to display `jpg` in `tkinter`

Answer (score 0):

You may use module [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html) to modify images - resize, convert colors, crop, rotate, add text and figures, etc.

It can also create `PhotoImage` for `tkinter`.
It is popular method to use `jpg` or other formats in `tkinter`.

```
from turtle import Shape, Screen, Turtle
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(width=500, height=500)
wn.bgcolor('white')

img = Image.open("lenna.png")
#w, h = img.size
w = int(img.width*0.1)
h = int(img.height*0.1)
img = img.resize( (w, h) )
pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

wn.addshape('pic', Shape("image", pic))

tr = Turtle("pic")
#while True:
#    wn.update()
wn.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia